# sp-io v7.0.0 not compiling

Tags: pallet

I added a custom pallet to the node-template-module. It was compiling before with just the `pallet-template` but not working with my newly added pallet. Here is the compilation error that I get:

```rs
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/dexer/work/substrate/dot-marketplace-v2/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/dexer/work/substrate/dot-marketplace-v2/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-8390732738fc4e81/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/dexer/work/substrate/dot-marketplace-v2/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.70.0-nightly (22f247c6f 2023-03-13)


  --- stderr
     Compiling sp-io v7.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.39#1837f423)
     Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/dexer/work/substrate/dot-marketplace-v2/runtime)
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `format` in `alloc`
      --> /Users/dexer/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/1837f42/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:1643:31
       |
  1643 |     let message = sp_std::alloc::format!("{}", info);
       |                                  ^^^^^^ could not find `format` in `alloc`

  error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`
      --> /Users/dexer/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/1837f42/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:1642:1
       |
  1642 | pub fn panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       |
       = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `sp_std` depends on)
       = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /Users/dexer/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-d66a635e2d91bd07.rlib
       = note: second definition in the local crate (`sp_io`)

  Some errors have detailed explanations: E0152, E0433.
  For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
```

Below is my `cargo.toml` file for the custom pallet:

```
[package]
name = "pallet-tasking"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.2.2", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, optional = true, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }
sp-std = { version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }

#local dependencies
tasking-traits = { default-features = false, path = "../../traits/tasking-traits" }
tasking-primitives = { default-features = false, path = "../../primitives/tasking-primitives" }

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { version = "7.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }
sp-io = { version = "7.0.0",  default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }
sp-runtime = { version = "7.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "frame-benchmarking?/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "sp-std/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = ["frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks"]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also disable `sp-std`'s default features.

You missed that one.

And I recommend you use subalfred to check this.

https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/check.html#features