# Not able to add any crates in substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, substrate-parachain-template, pallet-contracts, polkadot-sdk

I am working on substrate.where I want to use some of create like pinata_sdk,Openssl etc but I am not able to import or add in cargo.tmol file where I add I get this error: `

> --- stderr
> Compiling sp-io v23.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
> error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`
> --> /home/ubuntu/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:1664:1
> |
> 1664 | / pub fn panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
> 1665 | |     let message = sp_std::alloc::format!("{}", info);
> 1666 | |     #[cfg(feature = "improved_panic_error_reporting")]
> 1667 | |     {
> ...    |
> 1674 | |     }
> 1675 | | }
> | |_^
> |
> = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `bytes` depends on)
> = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /home/ubuntu/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-2bf3225a2841264f.rlib
> = note: second definition in the local crate (`sp_io`)

`.  I stuck in this from last 3 day I try all solution out there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sp-io v7.0.0 not compiling](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7655/sp-io-v7-0-0-not-compiling)

Comment: No i am not using "sp-std"